# How to call same page twice with different url in Web.sitemap file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page that is being redirected from two different places. here is the sitemap code :-

```
 <siteMapNode url="~/ProductsIndex.aspx" title="Product Management" description="Products Details">
    <siteMapNode url="~/AddNewProducts.aspx" title="Product Identification" description="Product Identification" />
</siteMapNode>

 <siteMapNode url="~/StoreAdminIndex.aspx" title="Store Administration" description="Store Administration">
 <siteMapNode url="~/AddNewProducts.aspx" title="Product Identification" description="Product Identification" />
</siteMapNode>
```

After searching on net I got following answer :- 
We need to add any query string.

```
  <siteMapNode url="~/StoreAdminIndex.aspx" title="Store Administration" description="Store Administration">
 <siteMapNode url="~/AddNewProducts.aspx?S=1" title="Product Identification" description="Product Identification" />
</siteMapNode>
```

But When I am using this code and I am passing some other querystring value the correct sitemap is not showing.
Eg. when I am redirecting to AddNewProducts.aspx page, It is like 
AddNewProducts.aspx?S=1&SId=7913 (Here we have one more query string SId).

And I don't want to use Session object to hold the SId.

Any Idea? how to solve this issue?

[Edit]
Here is the code :
When I am using following code :-

```
Response.Redirect("~/AddNewProducts.aspx?S=1", false);
```

It's working fine. but when I am using following code :

```
Response.Redirect("~/AddNewProducts.aspx?S=1&SId=" + hdnStoreId.Value.ToString(), false);
```

It's not working.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a session? Also, I don't fully understand your question. Why not just add another querystring in the link?

Comment: @webnoob, Thanks for reply. I don't want to use session because I need to pass more that six or seven querystring value, If I use session it will be very complicated that would be the last option for me. And if i use more that one querystring the correct breadcrumb does not appear, And that's what my question is about.

Comment: We need to see more code. Using more than one query string works, I assume there was an issue when you implemented it. Show us the code you used with multiple querystrings as it sounds like this is where you need the help.

Comment: When you say the second option doesn't work, is the querystring blank when you read it? What's not actually working? Have you debugged it to ensure `hndStoreId.Value` has a value?

Comment: I mean, when I use second option it shows the first breadcrumb, It should show the second breadcrumb. I debugged it. I dont see any error in hiddenfield value. Even if it is empty we have method to set default value. So for me hidden field, not an issue.

Comment: Well it must be an issue in your breadcrumb code .. If you have debugged it and know the value you are sending is Ok then this is the only logical place the issue could be.